# What's the simple way to print or format a custom type with libfmt?

Tags: c++, formatting, fmt

Suppose I've defined some type, e.g.

```
struct Foo { int a; float b; };
```

If I want to stream it to an ostream, I write an `operator<<` function, e.g.:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& foo)
{
  return os << '(' << a << ',' << b << ')';
}
```

Now I want to do the same thing, but in an `fmt::format()` or `fmt::print()` call. If I write:

```
fmt::print("{}\n", foo);
```

I'll get a bunch of errors, ending with something like:

```
/path/to/fmt/core.h:1073:9: error: static assertion failed: Cannot format argument. 
To make type T formattable provide a formatter<T> specialization:
https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#formatting-user-defined-types
```

Ok, so, I go [there](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#formatting-user-defined-types), and I see a bunch of examples, already the first of which is kind of complicated. What's the simplest thing I can write to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 7):

To simplify the example, let's assume you are only willing to accept `{}` formatting specifiers, without any additional string controlling how printing looks like. In that case, you would write this:

```
template <> class fmt::formatter<Foo> {
public:
  constexpr auto parse (format_parse_context& ctx) { return ctx.begin(); }
  template <typename Context>
  constexpr auto format (Foo const& foo, Context& ctx) const {
      return format_to(ctx.out(), "({}, {})", foo.a, foo.b);  // --== KEY LINE ==--
  }
};
```

That's it. A bit baroque, and you can't remove the first method (why?...) but not that terrible. Copy-paste this snippet from here; replace `Foo` with your type; and rewrite the actual formatting command on the KEY LINE.

Full example program:

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

struct Foo { int a; float b; };

template <>
class fmt::formatter<Foo> {
public:
  constexpr auto parse (format_parse_context& ctx) { return ctx.begin(); }
  template <typename Context>
  constexpr auto format (Foo const& foo, Context& ctx) const {
      return format_to(ctx.out(), "({},{})", foo.a, foo.b);
  }
};

int main () {
  Foo foo {123, 4.56};
  fmt::print("{}\n", foo);
}
```

See it working on [<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/6qq9dszh6).

Comment: 'template <> **struct** fmt::formatter<Foo> {' was correct in my case

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
#include "spdlog/fmt/ostr.h"

struct Foo { int a; float b; };

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& foo) {
    return os << "(" << foo.a << "," << foo.b << ")";
}

int main () {
    Foo foo {123, 4.56};
    fmt::print("{}\n", foo);
}
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/vrEWGP1fn

Comment: Interesting... going through an ostream operator<< gives you free fmt support. A few lines of code less, for sure, but means you have to drag in all of `<iostream>`. Anyway, +1.

Comment: No need to pull spdlog into this, there is `#include <fmt/ostream.h>` which enables ostream support.  See [fmt documentation](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html?highlight=ostream#std-ostream-support).